# Query Designer toolbar grayed out?

Tags: ssms

I am using the Query Designer in SQL Server Management Studio (on an Express 2008 database). I created a new Query, chose Design Query in Editor from the Query toolbar and was presented with a cool graphical query designer (a bit like the one in ACCESS). I selected the fields, which generated the T-SQL, and executed the query and thought awesome! However, I can then only modify the T-SQL manually, I cannot get back into the graphical designer as all the Query Designer toolbar options are grayed out.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Highlight the query text, then right-click, and select "Design Query in Editor...".